# Posting a base64 encoded PDF file with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, binary-data, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I'm trying to post a base64-encoded PDF file to a Zendesk file upload API endpoint but the file URL returned from the API shows that the file is corrupted.

First I receive the PDF as a base64-encoded string from a separate API call. Let's call it `base64String`.

If I do `window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + base64String)` I can view the PDF in my browser.

Now I am trying to follow the documentation [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/attachments#upload-files) for uploading files via the API. I can successfully complete a cURL call as shown in the example. However, the jQuery AJAX call will corrupt the PDF file.

```javascript
client.request({
  url: '/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=test.pdf',
  type: 'POST',
  data: atob(base64String),
  contentType: 'application/binary'
}).then(function(data) {
  window.open(data.upload.attachment.content_url);  // corrupt file
}, function(response) {
  console.log("Failed to upload file to Zendesk.");
  console.log(response);
});
```

Like I said, this will succeed but when I visit the `content_url` the PDF does not display. I am quite sure the file is being corrupt in the `POST` request.

I have tried uploading the file as a base64 string (without decoding with `atob()`) with no luck among other things.

**UPDATE**

I'm still not able to view the PDF after converting the base64 string to blob.

```js
var blob = base64ToBlob(base64String);
console.log(blob);  // Blob {size:39574, type: "application/pdf"}

client.request({
  url: '/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=test.pdf',
  type: 'POST',
  data: blob,
  processData: false,
  contentType: 'application/pdf'
}).then(function(data) {
  window.open(data.upload.attachment.content_url);  // corrupt file
}, function(response) {
  console.log("Failed to upload file to Zendesk.");
  console.log(response);
});

function base64ToBlob(byteString) {
  // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
  var blob = new Blob([ab], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  return blob;
};
```

Comment: Why do you set `contentType` to `"application/binary"`?

Comment: If you look at the [cURL example](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/attachments#upload-files) they have that header.

Comment: Have you tried handling the POST request to the server with another language to make sure that it's a client problem?

Comment: It is a unique convention but it hasn't given me issues in the past.

Comment: _"content_type string yes The content type of the image. Example value: "content_type": "image/png""_ Or, is that the response? Have you tried posting the full `data URI`, instead of only `base64` portion of `data URI`? `base64String` by itself is not a valid `data URI` representation of the file. _"It is a unique convention but it hasn't given me issues in the past."_ What have you tried in the past that was successful?

Comment: Try passing full `data URI` without wrapping in `atob()` call and setting `contentType` to `"application/pdf"`; or sending file as a `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer`, if the server can handle either of the two data types.

Comment: So posting `"data:application/pdf;base64," + base64String` instead of `atob(base64String)` did not work. I tried with `application/binary` and `application/pdf` `contentType`s.

Comment: _"I can successfully complete a cURL call as shown in the example"_ How did you achieve success using `cURL`? What are the formats which server can handle?

Comment: Basically from within the file's directory I ran the cURL command but changed `@file.dat` to the name of my file. AFAIK `application/binary` and `application/pdf` both work in cURL.

Comment: What did you pass as the file object at `cURL`? What is the value of `data.upload.attachment.content_url` at `.then()`?

Comment: Where does documentation describe expecting a `data URI` or `Blob` from `POST` request?

Comment: I passed a basic PDF file in the cURL request. `data.upload.attachment.content_url` is a download link for the file.

Comment: Have you tried using `FormData()` with `contentType` set to `false`, `var fd = new FormData(); fd.append("file", blob); data:fd;`? Or using `XMLHttpRequest()` `request.send(blob)` or `fetch()` `fetch("url", {method:"POST", body:blob})` to `POST` `Blob`, instead of `jQuery.ajax()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that the Zendesk app framework uses a jQuery AJAX wrapper for requests and the arraybuffer type is unsupported, so the file was getting corrupted. The app framework team has fixed the issue.

Comment: relevant xkcd comes to mind here :'(
How did you resolve this? Does arraybuffer now work?